# mostrar banner según la provincia del visitante con PHP

Tags: javascript

Buenas a ver si alguien me puede exar una mano, me gustaría poder mostrar banners diferentes según la ciudad o provincia.

este seria para el país pero me gustaría si es posible la provincia o ciudad.

```
<?php

$var = file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$location = json_decode($var);
if($location->countryCode == 'MX'){
echo 'contenido';
}else if($api->countryCode == 'AR'){
echo 'contenido';
}else if($api->countryCode == 'CO'){
echo 'contenido';
}else{
echo 'ooooopss...';
}

?>
```

espero me puedan ayudar.. Gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Puedes indicarnos el contenido de la variable $location después del json_decode? De momento lo único que se puede ver es que hay una propiedad llamada countryCode, pero no podemos saber si hay algo más que ayude a tu problema.

Comment: Buenas, te refieres a 'MX' ? son los códigos ISO de cada país

Comment: Por favor incluye lo que has intentado o investigado

Comment: en primera instancia se crea una variable y se usa file_get_contents para hacer una petición a ip-api.com. Posteriormente se llama a json_decode para obtener la información del país del visitante.

Este script funciona con los códigos ISO de cada país, intente con el codigo iso por provincia y ciudad y nada...voy bastante perdido

Comment: En el ejemplo que pones solo se ve algo llamado 'countryCode'. No se ve en tu código nada relacionado por provincia y otro campo. Edita tu pregunta y añade el resultado de un `print_r($location)` para ver qué opciones te llegan de resultado

Answer (score 1):

Es exactamente igual a como lo estás haciendo, por ejemplo aquí si el pais es España, comprueba si la provincia es Valencia:

```
<?php

$var = file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$location = json_decode($var);

if($location->countryCode == 'ES'){
    echo 'contenido es';
    if($location->regionName == 'Valencia') {
        echo ' valencia ';
    }
}else if($api->countryCode == 'AR'){
echo 'contenido ar';
}else if($api->countryCode == 'CO'){
echo 'contenido co';
}else{
echo 'ooooopss...';
}

?>
```